# Ajax not processing when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

So I am trying to use a simple Ajax function in a JSP using the JQueryUI.  I am simply passing in two text fields that are used in a form, and trying to populate two divs with them.  Nothing is happening at all when I click the button, I have tried putting console.logs in the ajax function and nothing is getting printed.

JSP code for button click call (full jquery as requested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#saveBtn').click(function() {  
          //define the handler function for click event inline (it doesn't need a name because we're just using it one time)
          // get the value of the search box
          console.log("you are in the ajax");
          var addressValue = $("#address").val();
          var creditValue = $('#creditcard').val();
          System.out.println("you are in the function");
          // send to the server (this is relative to our current page)
          $.ajax({

            url: "actions.InfoAjax.action",
            data: { // this is an embedded JSON object we'll send to server
              address: addressValue,
              creditcard: creditValue
            },
            dataType: 'json',  // tell JQuery to expect JSON back from the server
            success: function(ret) {  // this is called as soon as the server returns

              console.log(ret.address);
              console.log(ret.creditcard);
              $('#savedAddress').html(ret.address);
              $('#savedCC').html(ret.creditcard);


            }//success
          });//ajax

        });//click
      });//ready
    </script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<form action="post">
          <input type = "text" name="address" placeholder="Address" ></input></br>
           <input type = "text" name="creditcard" placeholder="Credit Card Number">  </input></br>
          <button type ="button" class ="btn btn-small" id="saveBtn">Save</button>
</form>
```

I have been trying to get this to work for hours, any help is appreciated.

Here are the errors i'm getting from the console:

```
 readyState: 4
responseText: "
↵
↵{
↵  "address": [null],
↵  "creditcard": [ test ]
↵}
↵
↵"

1: "parsererror"
2: SyntaxError
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "Unexpected token e"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
callee: function () {
length: 3
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: post your full jquery

Comment: agree "return false;" in your click event.

Comment: add this `$('#saveBtn').click(function() { alert(1))` to see if click is handled ...

Comment: @darshanags added full jquery

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: @ArunPJohny nope, it just doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Is there any errors messages in console?

Comment: are you saying you don't even get "you are in the ajax" in the console after clicking the button?

Comment: stupid question #1: do you even have <script> tag around your code. qustion #2: do you have your code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function () {//your code});` ?

Comment: @i-- yes i have script and yes to the second question :)

Comment: what about my prev comment?

Comment: @i-- i now have that in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function (e) { //define the handler function for click event inline (it doesn't need a name because we're just using it one time)
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the value of the search box
    console.log("you are in the ajax");
    var addressValue = $("#address").val();
    var creditValue = $('#creditcard').val();
    //System.out.println("you are in the function");
    // send to the server (this is relative to our current page)
    $.ajax({

        url : "actions.InfoAjax.action",
        data : { // this is an embedded JSON object we'll send to server
            address : addressValue,
            creditcard : creditValue
        },
        dataType : 'json', // tell JQuery to expect JSON back from the server
        success : function (ret) { // this is called as soon as the server returns

            console.log(ret.address);
            console.log(ret.creditcard);
            $('#savedAddress').html(ret.address);
            $('#savedCC').html(ret.creditcard);

        }, //success
        error : function () {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    }); //ajax

}); //click
```

Comment: e.preventDefault() its similar to "return false;"

Comment: Still the same results, no actions at all

Comment: @Landon That is why I added a `error` callback. Check your console for any errors and post them back here.

Comment: @Landon your jQuery ajax setup is configured to accept json as a response and the server is responding with `""`, which is invalid json. If for any reason you cannot send any data back with the response, you will need to *at least* send `{}` as your response. In other words, your current sever response is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery Docs, .click is a shortcut for .on('click', handler), try with

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Also make sure that your JS file containing the code or the inline script is loaded, along with jQuery on page load.

Comment: Here you a have a working example, using the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/4waup/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
   return false;
});

$('#foo').live('click', function() {
   return false;
});
```

Try it. "return false" on the last line before close the function may work.

Answer (score 0):

You can too make a new function. Make a form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#foo').submit(function() {
      // function here. try it!
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this and tell us

```
//System.out.println ?? check this
 });//ajax
    return false; 
});//click
```

Comment: He says nothing is happening at all

Comment: No results, what is that supposed to be checking?

Comment: in your console any error??, If you are using Chrome looks the Network tab and check the "xhr" and give your button click.